# LINQ to XML - where clause in Let statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

More troubles with LINQ. Just hoping that someone could please help.

Here's the structure I'm working with;

```
<root>
   <Level1>
     <Level2>
       <Level3>
         <Car>
           <Price PaymentType="Cash">200</Price>
           <Price PaymentType="Credit">500</Price>
         </Car>
       </Level3>
     </Level2>
   </Level1>
</root>
```

I'm trying to create two Let variables, that do this;

```
Let priceCash = ??? // should return 200
Let priceCredit = ??? // should return 500
```

To complicate things more, not all Cars have a Credit Price. For these I'd like to return -1.

Here's the butchered code I came up with;

```
// get all Price elements
let PriceList = CarList.Elements("Price") 

// try to get the first Price element where PaymentType==Cash
let priceCash = PriceList.Where(c => PriceList.Attributes("PaymentType").First().Value == "Cash")

// try to get the first Price element where PaymentType==Credit
let priceCredit = PriceList.Where(c => PriceList.Attributes("PaymentType").First().Value == "Credit")
```

Is there a better way to do that? It seems to work, but then I run into trouble here;

```
select new MyObj
{
    Price1 = priceCash == null ? -1 : priceCash.ElementAt(0).Value,
    Price2 = priceCredit == null ? -1 : priceCredit.ElementAt(0).Value,
}).ToList<MyObj>();
```

ElementAt(0) is causing an exception when the element isn't found.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use `Attribute` method, instead of `Attributes().First` chain and `(string)XAttribute` conversion instead of `XAttribute.Value` property:

```
// get all Price elements
let PriceList = CarList.Elements("Price") 

// try to get the first Price element where PaymentType==Cash
let priceCash = PriceList.Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("PaymentType") == "Cash")

// try to get the first Price element where PaymentType==Credit
let priceCredit = PriceList.Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("PaymentType") == "Credit")
```

And what even more important, use `DefaultIfEmpty` to get `-1` when elements are not present:

```
select new MyObj
{
    Price1 = priceCash.Select(x => (int)x).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First(),
    Price2 = priceCredit.Select(x => (int)x).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).First()
}).ToList<MyObj>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should be more robust:

```
// try to get the first Price element where PaymentType==Cash
let priceCash = PriceList.FirstOrDefault(c => ((string)c.Attribute("PaymentType")) == "Cash")

// try to get the first Price element where PaymentType==Credit
let priceCredit = PriceList.FirstOrDefault(c => ((string)c.Attribute("PaymentType")) == "Credit")

select new MyObj
{
    Price1 = priceCash == null ? -1 : (int)priceCash,
    Price2 = priceCredit == null ? -1 : (int)priceCredit
}).ToList<MyObj>();
```

Comment: thanks mate, but "(string)PriceList.Attributes" doesn't work. "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute>' to 'string'

Comment: @ausgeorge: Fixed. It is `PriceList.Attribute` - singular

Comment: @Rezoan: No. Removing the `Value` was the whole point of my answer.

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. Attribute is not a known member, however. Attributes is.

Comment: @ausgeorge: Boy... Fixed another error. `c.Attribute` instead of `PriceList.Attribute`. Sorry for the confusion. Hopefully, all errors are gone now.